# "was fiction" vs "were fictions"

Tags: sentence-construction

I came across this sentence in Barron's "504 essential words" book:

> We hardly ever believed Vinny because what he said **was** usually **fiction**.

but I guess the correct form should be something like this:

> We hardly ever believed Vinny because what he said **were** usually **fictions**.

Am I wrong? Or both are correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first sentence is correct:

> We hardly ever believed Vinny because what he said was usually fiction.

You probably feel that *what* refers to *the things he said* which seems like a plural countable noun phrase.

But we can also think of it as singular, such as *the set of all the things he said* or *the typical thing he said.*

How do you feel about *They sometimes met in the daytime, but when they usually met it was night*?

Or *What their meetings seemed like to him was a waste of time*?

Those are similar ways of naming groups or collections of things with singular nouns.

Your second example is grammatical, but probably less common or natural in this context.

Comment: Yes, fiction here is the best choice. As opposed to: science or philosophy. The noun form is best. 2) is grammatical but not said.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I think your version reads more awkwardly, because “fiction” usually gets treated as a mass noun. Barron’s has it right.

However, we could tweak your version and get something that sounds okay:

> We hardly ever believed Vinny because **the things** he said **were** usually **fictitious**.

By changing “what he said” to “the things he said”, we can use a plural verb. And by changing the noun *fiction* to the adjective *fictitious*, the end of the sentence works, too.

Comment: Hmm . . . We both recognize what's correct/standard/conventional, but as so often is the case with grammar, we have slightly different explanations. In support of yours, I think of something like *What she usually drank was milk.* If it was *milks,* we'd think it meant different kinds (countable noun). My mind went to how we conceptualize the thing/s represented by *what* as a pronoun. Interesting. I can't quite wrap my mind around the issue!

Comment: I just cannot imagine saying: the thing he said were fictitious. Maybe: his explanations were fictitious.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree; my utterance would probably go more like this: _We hardly ever believed Vinny because he lied all the time_.  (I was trying to stay as close to the original as I could yet make it sound more grammatical.) As unlikely as I might be to say, "usually fictitious," that's still easier to imagine myself saying than, "usually fictions."

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but the first version is more appropriate and natural in this case..

"fiction" is usually used as a mass noun, referring to a collection of stories or statements that are not true.

However, it can be used as a singular noun, but it's usually done in a more restricted context. From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fiction)

> 2. Something that is invented or untrue.
>      *‘they were supposed to be keeping up the fiction that they were happily married’*
>      2.1 A belief or statement which is false, but is often held to be true because it is expedient to do so.
>          *‘the notion of the country being a democracy is a polite fiction’*

Your second version is using "fictions" in this way, but the intent doesn't seem to include these nuances.

Comment: The explanation is good.

Answer (score -1):

Only the first sentence is correct because the subject clause "what he said" needs the singular form of the verb.

Comment: Even though we don't often hear _fictions_ used in the plural, I thought your [original answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/217512/1) had some useful examples. I liked your answer better before you cut away so much of it.

Comment: I would have upvoted your original answer. (After seeing the above comment and looking at it.)